# Signal names for control+S and control+Q

Tags: c, signals

I want to set a function handler for when I press ctrl + S and ctrl + Q, but I don't know what are the names for these signals.

I have found this list https://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/courses/moved.Building/signals.pdf but I am kinda lost, and I cannot understand which description fits these signals. I would appreciate some help. Thanks.

Comment: You can't catch these as signals, because they don't generate signals.

Answer (score 4):

CTRL+S and CTRL-Q are XOFF and XON (or STOP and START) respectively, which are flow control for the terminal and don't generate any signals. Instead this is handled by the tty driver/ldisc.

You could disable `IXON` via [`termios`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html) and read those directly, but they won't act as any sort of signal or interrupt.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have disabled the default behaviour with this command: stty -ixon -ixoff. Now how will I detect If a user presses ctrl + S in order to act accordingly?

Comment: normal read of the keyboard